# Using React-pdf, followed instructions but still does not load. How to fix this error?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, pdf

I have been following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) to view my pdf on my website, for some reason it won't load and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Document, Page} from 'react-pdf';

class Resume extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      numPages: null,
      pageNumber: 1
    }
  }

  onDocumentLoad = ( {numPages}) => {
    this.setState({numPages});
  }

  render() {
    const {pageNumber, numPages} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Document
          file = '../files/resume.pdf'
          onLoadSuccess = {this.onDocumentLoad}
          >
            <Page pageNumber = {pageNumber} />
        </Document>
        <p> Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Resume;
```

Here is my directory and files along with it!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think it wants a file path, but a URL to send a request to. Try putting `resume.pdf` in the `public` directory and write `file='/resume.pdf'` instead.

Comment: tried it, same result :(

Comment: Try restarting the server after you added the file to the `public` directory.

Comment: still nothing. i do get compiling warnings saying stuff like :

Comment: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannt be statically extracted ... (for ...build/pdf.jf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
```

Add the last line to import statement. Worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a problem where the component just saying it's loading the pdf but never actually loads - no error messages, nothing. But for reference, here are the important parts of my component. Notice that I followed their instructions, React 16.6+ and this is for accessing a PDF via a URL:

```
import { Document } from 'react-pdf/dist/entry.webpack';
import { pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;



  render () {
    return (<Document 
      // noData={console.log("No Data was found")}
      onLoadError={(error) => alert('Error while loading document! ' + error.message)}
      file={{ url: 'http://localhost:3000/resume.pdf' }}
      />)
  }
```

Comment: this is less so an answer and more so a question

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the file-loader configured in your webpack config?

```
{
    test: /\.pdf$/,
    use: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]',
},
```

I'm using file-loader 3.0.1 and I can load the PDF's from my file system just fine.

You would also of course need to import it at the top like so:

```
import resume from '../files/resume.pdf';
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and found a solution here https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/321.

`import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';`

Add this to your constructor.

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers didn't solve my problem either.  I found that I had to move my pdf folder to the public folder to fix.  Hopefully that solves your issue too.